# Shuffle two list at once with same order

Tags: python, list, sorting, shuffle

I'm using the `nltk` library's `movie_reviews` corpus which contains a large number of documents. My task is get  predictive performance of these reviews with pre-processing of the data and without pre-processing. But there is problem, in lists `documents` and `documents2` I have the same documents and I need shuffle them in order to keep same order in both lists. I cannot shuffle them separately because each time I shuffle the list, I get other results. That is why I need to shuffle the at once with same order because I need compare them in the end (it depends on order). I'm using python 2.7

Example (in real are strings tokenized, but it is not relative):

```
documents = [(['plot : two teen couples go to a church party , '], 'neg'),
             (['drink and then drive . '], 'pos'),
             (['they get into an accident . '], 'neg'),
             (['one of the guys dies'], 'neg')]

documents2 = [(['plot two teen couples church party'], 'neg'),
              (['drink then drive . '], 'pos'),
              (['they get accident . '], 'neg'),
              (['one guys dies'], 'neg')]
```

And I need get this result after shuffle both lists:

```
documents = [(['one of the guys dies'], 'neg'),
             (['they get into an accident . '], 'neg'),
             (['drink and then drive . '], 'pos'),
             (['plot : two teen couples go to a church party , '], 'neg')]

documents2 = [(['one guys dies'], 'neg'),
              (['they get accident . '], 'neg'),
              (['drink then drive . '], 'pos'),
              (['plot two teen couples church party'], 'neg')]
```

I have this code:

```
def cleanDoc(doc):
    stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    clean = [token.lower() for token in doc if token.lower() not in stopset and len(token) > 2]
    final = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in clean]
    return final

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

documents2 = [(list(cleanDoc(movie_reviews.words(fileid))), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle( and here shuffle documents and documents2 with same order) # or somehow
```

Answer (score 312, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
import random

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]

c = list(zip(a, b))

random.shuffle(c)

a, b = zip(*c)

print a
print b

[OUTPUT]
['a', 'c', 'b']
[1, 3, 2]
```

Of course, this was an example with simpler lists, but the adaptation will be the same for your case.

Comment: (noob question) - what does the * mean?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, It means unpack the values of c so it is called as `zip(1,2,3)` instead of `zip([1,2,3])`

Comment: I used this solution before and `a` and `b` were lists at the end. With Python 3.6.8, at the end of the same example, I get `a` and `b` as tuples.

Comment: ...Tuples... so just a=list(a) and b=list(b)

Comment: how would you do this for 3 or 4 arrays?

Comment: Same approach, zip can take a variable number of arguments

Answer (score 74):

I get a easy way to do this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8,9])

indices = np.arange(a.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)

a = a[indices]
b = b[indices]
# a, array([3, 4, 1, 2, 0])
# b, array([8, 9, 6, 7, 5])
```

Comment: The original post is about normal lists in python, but I needed a solution for numpy arrays. You just saved my day!

Comment: It seems like `np.random.permutation(a.shape[0])` would be simpler

Comment: Saved my day to reverse it. Use inverse_perm = np.argsort(permutation) and np.array(my_array)[inverse_perm] to reverse it.

Answer (score 21):

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

a = ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a_shuffled, b_shuffled = shuffle(np.array(a), np.array(b))
print(a_shuffled, b_shuffled)

#random output
#['e' 'c' 'b' 'd' 'a'] [5 3 2 4 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Shuffle an arbitray number of lists simultaneously.

```
from random import shuffle

def shuffle_list(*ls):
  l =list(zip(*ls))

  shuffle(l)
  return zip(*l)

a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8,9]

a1,b1 = shuffle_list(a,b)
print(a1,b1)

a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8,9]
c = [10,11,12,13,14]
a1,b1,c1 = shuffle_list(a,b,c)
print(a1,b1,c1)
```

Output:

```
$ (0, 2, 4, 3, 1) (5, 7, 9, 8, 6)
$ (4, 3, 0, 2, 1) (9, 8, 5, 7, 6) (14, 13, 10, 12, 11)
```

Note:
objects returned by `shuffle_list()` are `tuples`.

P.S.
`shuffle_list()` can also be applied to `numpy.array()`

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

a1,b1 = shuffle_list(a,b)
print(a1,b1)
```

Output:

```
$ (3, 1, 2) (6, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 5):

Easy and fast way to do this is to use random.seed() with random.shuffle() . It lets you generate same random order many times you want.
It will look like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
seed = random.random()
random.seed(seed)
a.shuffle()
random.seed(seed)
b.shuffle()
print(a)
print(b)

>>[3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
>>[8, 6, 9, 7, 10]
```

This also works when you can't work with both lists at the same time, because of memory problems.

Comment: shouldnt it be random.shuffle(a) ?

Comment: I think `getstate/setstate` would work better than assigning a particular seed.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the order of the values in a variable, then sort the arrays simultaneously:

```py
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

order = range(len(array1))
random.shuffle(order)

newarray1 = []
newarray2 = []
for x in range(len(order)):
    newarray1.append(array1[order[x]])
    newarray2.append(array2[order[x]])

print newarray1, newarray2
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

```
import numpy as np

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]

rng = np.random.default_rng()

state = rng.bit_generator.state
rng.shuffle(a)
# use same seeds for a & b!
rng.bit_generator.state = state # set state to same state as before
rng.shuffle(b)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'a', 'c']
[2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the second argument of the shuffle function to fix the order of shuffling.

Specifically, you can pass the second argument of shuffle function a zero argument function which returns a value in [0, 1). The return value of this function fixes the order of shuffling. (By default i.e. if you do not pass any function as the second argument, it uses the function `random.random()`. You can see it at line 277 [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py).)

This example illustrates what I described:

```
import random

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

r = random.random()            # randomly generating a real in [0,1)
random.shuffle(a, lambda : r)  # lambda : r is an unary function which returns r
random.shuffle(b, lambda : r)  # using the same function as used in prev line so that shuffling order is same

print a
print b
```

Output:

```
['e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
[5, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: The `random.shuffle` function calls the `random` function more than once, so using a `lambda` that always returns the same value may have unintended effects on the output order.

Comment: You are right. This will be a biased shuffling, depending on the value of r. It may be practically good for many cases but not always.