# How to shuffle multiple iterables in same order?

Tags: python, random, python-3.7, iterable

I seek a plain Python function that accepts an arbitrary number of iterables (tuples, lists, dictionaries), and returns them shuffled *in the same order*:

```py
a = (1, 2, {3: 4}, 5)
b = [(5,6), [7,8], [9,0], [1,2]]
c = {'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard', 0: ('x',2)}

x, y, z = magic(a, b, c)
print(x, y, z, sep='\n')
# ({3: 4}, 1, 2)
# [[9, 0], (5, 6), [7, 8]]
# {0: ('x', 2), 'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard'}
```

The function must:

1. Return iterables shuffled in the same order (see above)
2. Accept any number of iterables
3. Preserve iterables *types*
4. Support nested iterables of any *depth* and *type*
5. *Not* shuffle nested elements themselves (eg. `[7,8]` above doesn't become `[8,7]`)
6. Return iterables with length of shortest iterable's length w/o raising error (see above)

OK if using Numpy, random, etc for the shuffle step (e.g. `np.random.shuffle(magic_packing)`), but *cannot* be a high-level library method (uses multiprocessing, encoding, etc - should be 'plain')

---

I've seen [related SO's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289547/shuffle-two-list-at-once-with-same-order), but could not adapt them to such a generalized case. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: So you mean `tuple`, `list` and `dict` objects **only**? Note, `dict` objects are only ordered in Python +3.7... Also can you assume that the objects will have the same length?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, only - and suppose I'll add a tag, but the question can be dumbed down to exclude dicts for 3.6-

Comment: And sorry, but what does this have to do with `numpy`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The mentioned method shuffles data structures (arrays, lists, tuples, dicts, etc), just as an example (as Python doesn't have a built-in for that)

Comment: You can't shuffle a dict.

Comment: @smac89 Yes, you can

Comment: You say it with such confidence that I almost doubt myself. Can you show an example?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon of course it does. In the `random` module.

Comment: You want to shuffle the nested iterables too?

Comment: @DanielMesejo No, as can be seen from the example; I'll still clarify in the question

Comment: VTCing as multiple concerns in one question. That's off topic at SO as not useful for further readers. Pick one -- what specific item in your long list of features are you having a problem with?

Comment: And if you are looking for ways to improve an existing solution, that's the domain of [codereview.se] (do read their guidelines).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```py
def ordered_shuffle(*args):
    args_types = [type(arg) for arg in args]                               # [1]
    _args      = [arg if type(arg)!=dict else arg.items() for arg in args] # [2]
    args_split = [arg for arg in zip(*_args)]                              # [3]
    args_shuffled = random.sample(args_split, len(args_split))             # [4]
    args_shuffled = map(tuple, zip(*args_shuffled))                        # [5]
    return [args_types[i](arg) for i, arg in enumerate(args_shuffled)]     # [6]
```

---

**EXPLANATION**:
take a simpler case, step-by-step:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ([1,2], [3,4], [5,6])
c = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

# [1]: list, tuple, dict
# [2]: [[1, 2, 3],
#       ([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]),
#       dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])]
# [3]: [(1, [1, 2], ('a', 1)), 
#       (2, [3, 4], ('b', 2)), 
#       (3, [5, 6], ('c', 3))]
# [4]: [(1, [1, 2], ('a', 1)), 
#       (3, [5, 6], ('c', 3)), 
#       (2, [3, 4], ('b', 2))]
# [5]: (1, 2, 3)
#      ([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])
#      (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3))
# [6]: [(1, 2, {3: 4}),
#       [(5, 6), [7, 8], [9, 0]],
#       {'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard', 0: ('x', 2)}]
```

1. Store original types to restore later
2. By default, Python iterates only over dict KEYS - we need values also
3. Python dictionaries cannot be shuffled directly - but indirectly by first casting key-value pairs into *tuples*; all iterables should also be iterated *concurrently* to restructure, accomplished w/ `zip`
4. Use Python's native `random`
5. Can cast into `list` also, but `tuple` is more efficient
6. Restore original types and return as tuple to be unpacked as `x, y = ordered_shuffle(a, b)`

---

**Lambda solution:** (credit: [Gloweye](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/180641/gloweye))

```py
ordered_shuffle = lambda *args:[type(args[i])(arg) for i, arg in enumerate(map(tuple, 
            zip(*random.sample([y for y in zip(*[x if type(x)!=dict else x.items() 
            for x in args])], min(len(z) for z in args)))))]
```

---

**Shortest & Fastest solution**: (credit: [GZ0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/207952/gz0)) (shorten var names to make it shortest)

```py
def ordered_shuffle(*args):
    zipped_args = list(zip(*(a.items() if isinstance(a, dict) else a for a in args)))
    random.shuffle(zipped_args)
    return [cls(elements) for cls, elements in zip(map(type, args), zip(*zipped_args))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic approach:

```
import random
def shuffle_containers(*args):
    min_length = min(map(len, args))
    idx = list(range(min_length))
    random.shuffle(idx)
    results = []
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            results.append([arg[i] for i in idx])
        elif isinstance(arg, tuple):
            results.append(tuple(arg[i] for i in idx))
        elif isinstance(arg, dict):
            items = list(arg.items())
            results.append(dict(items[i] for i in idx))
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Encountered", type(arg),
                "expecting only list, dict, or tuple"
            )
    return results
a = (1, 2, {3: 4}, 5)
b = [(5,6), [7,8], [9,0], [1,2]]
c = {'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard', 0: ('x',2)}
x, y, z = shuffle_containers(a, b, c)
print(x, y, z, sep='\n')
```

Note, this will ignore any items passed the length of the smallest container, if you don't want that, it will require more complicated logic.

EDIT:

Here it is in two lines of code:

```
def shuffle_containers(*args):
    min_length = min(map(len, args)); idx = list(range(min_length)); random.shuffle(idx)
    return [ [arg[i] for i in idx] if isinstance(arg, list) else tuple(arg[i] for i in idx) if isinstance(arg, tuple) else dict(list(args.items())[i] for i in idx) ]
```

Of course, the above is much less readble, less efficient, and less simple. Don't do stuff like that.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon what would be "simpler", this is about as simple as it gets. In any case, how is this supposed to work if you want to maintain the order, say, `[1,2,3,4]` and `['a','b','c']`, what would you do if it didn't ignore `4` in the first list?

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? I could condense this into a horrible list-comprehension that would require 6 lines, but that wouldn't be "simpler" that would be "unreadble and unpythonic".

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

a = (1, 2, {3: 4}, 5)
b = [(5,6), [7,8], [9,0], [1,2]]
c = {'arrow': 5, 'knee': 'guard', 0: ('x',2)}

def magic(*x):
    out = []
    # 6. length of shortest iterable
    min_len = min(len(a_org) for a_org in x)
    for a_org in x:
        if isinstance(a_org, list) or isinstance(a_org, tuple):
            indices = list(range(len(a_org)))
            random.shuffle(indices)
            a_copy = type(a_org)(a_org[i] for i in indices[:min_len])
        elif isinstance(a_org, dict):
            indices = list(a_org.keys())
            random.shuffle(indices)
            a_copy = {i:a_org[i] for i in indices[:min_len]}
        else:
            raise "not supported type"

        out.append(a_copy)
    return tuple(out)

print(magic(a, b, c))
```

Comment: Works, but fails 6

Comment: oh, i didn't see than constraint when I wrote this. It seems my answer has the same spirit as @juanpa.arrivillaga