# Keras, simple CNN with binary classification doesn't converge — minimal example (from DeepLizard)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to NN and Keras. I have tried [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFJeN9V1ZsI) from DeepLizard and followed it until the lady showed the first training results ~30min in. I followed the steps exactly except the lines with 'shuffle' since that was not how it is supposed to be used (to my knowledge). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random as random
from random import randint
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from random import shuffle

train_labels = []
train_samples = []

for i in range(50):
  random_younger = randint(13,64)
  train_samples.append(random_younger)
  train_labels.append(1)

  random_older = randint(65,100)
  train_samples.append(random_older)
  train_labels.append(0)

for i in range (1000):
  random_younger = randint(13,64)
  train_samples.append(random_younger)
  train_labels.append(0)

  random_older = randint(65,100)
  train_samples.append(random_older)
  train_labels.append(1)

train_samples = np.array(train_samples)
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)
shuffle(train_samples)
shuffle(train_labels)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
scaled_train_samples = scaler.fit_transform(train_samples. reshape(-1,1))

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

model = Sequential([Dense(units=16, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'),
                Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
                Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')])

model.summary()

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=scaled_train_samples, y=train_labels, batch_size=5, epochs=30, shuffle=True, verbose=2)
```

My NN doesn't learn staying at 50% accuracy all the time. I tried to vary the #of layers and epochs, I have checked the data types and structure. Can someone help with the first in my life minimal example? Thanks!

Comment: Try representing the ages in binary, arrays of zeros and ones, instead than using integers

Comment: I actually think shuffle is not needed there at all. I think since "model.fit" shuffles by default, it was a bug in her code. The code, as she wrote it, doesn't work, but if I delete the lines with "shuffle" everything works as expected.

Comment: You're shuffling the `x` and `y` independently

Comment: @NicolasGervais is right.
This part needs to be modified:
shuffle(train_samples)
shuffle(train_labels)
This thread could help for your case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289547/shuffle-two-list-at-once-with-same-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, I was shuffling x and y independently. In the tutorial I have reference "shuffle" is used the way it is not supposed to work, see the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_shuffle.asp). My solution:

```
c = list(zip(train_samples, train_labels))

shuffle(c)

train_samples, train_labels = zip(*c)
train_samples = np.array(train_samples)
train_labels=np.array(train_labels)
```